# Apply a bearing to GoogleMap camera bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on an application that uses Google Maps API.
My map is displayed with a defined bearing and rotation/compass are disabled.

I'd like to add Camera Bounds to my map so that the user does not leave the area of interest.

However the API seems to provide only one method for that, which is

```
GoogleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(LatLngBounds)
```

The issue is that LatLngBounds are "boxes" aligned with latitude and longitude.
So on my map that has a bearing, the camera bounds have a diamond shape instead of a square one, which is a bit weird.

Is there a way I can set some Camera Bounds that are not Latitude/Longitude aligned ?

I thought of writing a workaround with a CameraMoveListener that would trigger a CameraUpdate, but it's a bit of work for a result that I believe would be not that great in term of user experience.

Comment: You can make all the points you need to be on the screen. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to quickly test your workaround you can use the `CameraUpdateAnimator` from my project [MapUtils](https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils)